# Can you identify this 3x4 black plate with studs only going down the middle?

Tags: part-identification, collectable-minifigures

I need help in identifying this piece so that I can search for it on BrickLink.
It is a platform for minifigures. It comes with the "mystery minifigure".

[image: minifig baseplate]

Comment: It is routinely used to display minifigs. The 3X4 area provides sufficient room for most minifigs. I've seen some special ones that take up more room than that.

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to find this piece by looking up *any* of the collectible minifigures on Bricklink and looking at the [set inventory](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=col13-14).

This piece is the **[Tile, Modified 3 x 4 with 4 Studs in Center (88646)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=88646&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)**.

It is classified on Bricklink under the category 'Tile, Modified'.